# What kind of scaling method is it, when you add new software to a single server to handle more users?

Tags: web-server, varnish, scalability, scaling

I have read about scaling (in terms of terminology and methods). This got me confused about the following:

On a single computer, running a web server (say apache), if the system administrator adds a front, caching, reverse-proxy such as Varnish, which in that scenario increase the amount of requests this server is able to handle.

My question:

Setting up such cache increases the capacity of the server to handle work, hence scales it, but without increasing neither the amount of nodes or the node's capacity.

**What is the name for this type of scaling?**

Answer (score 2):

It's called caching. Or whatever other term you could think up for it.

Honestly, this is not really *scaling* per se, but is changing how your application is delivered at a fundamental level.

Scaling typically refers to load balancing across multiple nodes or at the very least, between multiple application servers on the same physical system.

Comment: Dear @EEAA, that's what I was thinking as well but in various (and numerous!) article, this is referred as *scaling*, still and I'm rather confused, exactly for the reasons you've mentioned, as to how it should be referred to.

Comment: It shouldn't be called scaling.  Scaling is something that is incrementally extensible.  Caching static or nearly static content is just correct architecture; you can't use it to actually scale anything.